# Wait for a JDBC write() operation to be completed to run another PTransform in a Dataflow template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow job (batch) that runs fine when not using a template, but I absolutely need to use templates to automate the execution based on events in Cloud Storage, so I use Cloud Functions for that.

The problem is that my pipeline has a task that writes data into a table with JdbcIO. After writing, I need to do some post processing stuff, like dropping some staging tables. I thought I could use the Wait.on() method, but it expects a PCollection signal while JDBCIO write() method returns a PDone.

I guess I could run two pipelines, but that would be an overkill because 
(i) The post processing phase is simple 
(ii) I would need a pipeline orchestrator

What would be the best workaround for this without any overkill in performance and costs?

The only solution I could think of is to write data within a ParDo method to return a PCollection, but I think the JDBC write() method is the proper way to write in a JDBC sink. If anyone has had this problem and came up with a solution, I would be really grateful if you could share.

I've seen many people having this problem as well (most of them with BigQueryIO). I think this is a really requested feature. Is there a reason why Apache Beam doesn't support this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Performing the writes in `ParDos` and emitting the write results is a [reasonable thing to do](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/authoring-overview/#write-transforms).

The reason why specific IOs don't implement a behavior similar to what you describe is mostly just because it has been like that historically, and in some cases I think it is probably not very trivial.

There does not seem to be a deep reason not to do it though, and as you're saying a lot of people want this. I think there's already some similar work ongoing for `FileIO`.

It would definitely make sense for `JdbcIO` to return a `PCollection` of the objects representing the write results, but I am not aware of any specific ongoing work on this.

If you end up implementing something like this, please consider [contributing it to Beam](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/).

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with Beam yet. Do you know any example of how to do the writes in ParDos in a reliable way? It seems that the sink's write() method takes care of failures/logging/parallelism in a secure way I'm afraid I'm not able to do it myself.

Even the documentation states that "this section needs further explanation".